# how can I debug with the OpenCV source code

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I am using VS2010 with OpenCV 2.3.1, and opencv is installed by using *OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack*. Now I want to understand the facedetect sample (opencv\samples\c\facedetect.cpp) in detail, I wanna know how to process the specific xml feature file (haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml), and how to decide which feature to be used. These are all
in the CascadeClassifier class, but when I use "go to definition", the result file is a .hpp
head file, so where is the implementation file? when I use vs2010 to debug, the debugger can not locate the implementation file either. some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Add the opencv\modules directory to the 'source' entry in the vs-directories tab in the project settings. And make sure the pdb files are in the same directory as the debug dlls